# ext.net gridpanel foreign key filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, ext.net, gridpanel

my doubt is very simple, I just wanna show a name of User instead a ID. I did this before inside a Combobox, but now, I don't need to select. Just show the name. So, I should put a store inside Column? *Id_usuario* is the foreign key.

```
<ext:Column
     runat="server"
     DataIndex="id_usuario"
     Text="Responsável"
     Flex="2"
     Align="Center">
         //Here I want put a Store.
</ext:Column>
```

Comment: question is not clear,if u wanna put username ,just insert other colum and show it

Comment: You need to use a renderer.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use Render, but I already solved the problem by doing a JOIN in SqlDataSource.